# How to share variable value between requests in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4.2. In a controller I have a method which took a lot of time to complete making some heavy calculations. I want to inform the user of calculations progress. My idea was to have @progress variable which is updated during calculations and is read by different action processing AJAX requests from frontend. But this idea fails - I always have the default 0 value in AJAX action while the variable is updating in long method. I've tried @@progress, $progress and session[:progress] but with the exactly same results.
Now I'm considering to make a model for storing progress in database and reading it from there, but I can't believe it couldn't be done by some more simple means.
Please share your thoughts!

Comment: Looks like you need background job and ActionCable here

Comment: Would it be simpler than just have a special model for this purpose?

Comment: It's not about simplicity, it's about correctness

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Theoretical:**

The usual approach for these cases is to perform the job asynchronously from the HTTP handler process (so the end-user is not waiting too long for a response from the webserver).

This means:

1. delegate the heavy work to a background job,
2. somehow make the client-side aware of when the job is done (2 options here).

---

**Practical** (application of the theoretical above in a context of a Rails app):

1. Background job: The rails community provide a wide variety of gems (+ built-in solution `ActiveJob`) to do async jobs (= background tasks). They can be divided into 2 main categories:

- **persisted** state: write a file on disk with the current state so the queue can be resumed if server reboots (`DelayedJob`, `Que`)
- **in-memory** state: usually faster, but the queue is lost if server reboots (`Resque`, `Sidekiq`)

2. surface to client-side:
   There are two main options here:

- **polling**: client-side AJAX call to the back-end every X seconds to check if the background job is done
- **subscribing** via web socket: client-side connecting via web socket to the server and listening to an event triggered when the job is done (ex: `ActionCable` as pointed out by @Vasilisa)

---

**Opinion-based:**

If you want to keep it simple, I would go with a very simple implementation: `Resque` for the back-end and a polling system for the front-end.

If you want something complete, capable of resisting server reboots and restoring the queue where it was before the crash, I would use a persisted version (`DelayedJob` for example) or wrap the in-memory solution with your own persisting logic.

Comment: I use that in my project. Good explanation! :)